# Can't use javascript debug terminal anymore

Tags: javascript-debugger

I've previously been able to use the debug terminal without any issue, but now when I try to open it (by clicking the little down arrow next to the new terminal plus symbol and clicking "JavaScript Debug Terminal". I get the following error:

`No Terminal profile provider registered for id "extension.js-debug.debugTerminal"`

I've googled and come up empty handed. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thansk in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue where I had downloaded 2 different versions of the Javascript Debugger, the default one which gets shipped with the editor, and the nightly version. Please validate the same if you're able to see 2 profiles in the terminal with name "JavaScript Debug Terminal" as follows -

[image: Terminal Profiles Screenshot]

and also in the debug panel -

[image: Debug Panel Screenshot]

**Solution**

I uninstalled the "nightly" extension of JavaScript Debugger as follows -

[image]

**Disabling or uninstalling one of the Debug Extensions should solve the problem**. The answer is based on the preliminary details that you have specified, if this doesn't solve your problem, please help with more specifications into the issue via comments.

Comment: This wasn't the issue for me (my issue has resolved itself but I honestly can't remember how) but upvoting as it may help someone else. Thanks!